# How can select rows where two columns do not equal a value?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a table where each row has a `category` and `subcategory`.

I want to select all rows except where a specific `category` and `subcategory`.

My data looks like this:

```
| category | subcategory |
|----------|-------------|
| Color    | Orange      |
| Fruit    | Apple       |
| Fruit    | Orange      |
| Fruit    | Banana      |
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
| category | subcategory |
|----------|-------------|
| Color    | Orange      |
| Fruit    | Banana      |
```

This is what I've tried but obviously doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    (category <> 'Fruit' AND subcategory = 'Orange') and
    (category <> 'Fruit' AND subcategory = 'Apple')
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how I can get this to work. Does SQL have a way to say `where not (this and this)` because I still want the "Fruit" category and I still want the "Orange" subcategory.

Comment: we can guarantee that there will be zero rows that have subcategory = 'Orange' AND have subcategory = 'Apple'.  There is no value of subcategory that satisfies both of those conditions. I'm thinking the result you are after would be returned if we replaced the "`) and (`" with "`) or (`".

Comment: Do you want to exclude specific rows by their values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So then why not try a NOT?

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE NOT (category = 'Fruit' AND subcategory IN ('Orange', 'Apple'))
```

Comment: So easy. Thanks. For some reason, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to the one below

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    (category <> 'Fruit' AND subcategory = 'Orange') OR
    (category = 'Fruit' AND subcategory = 'Banana')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `subcategory = 'Apple'` be `subcategory ='Banana'` based on the result he wants?

Comment: Regardless it won't work because it doesn't include ANY categories that are 'Fruit'. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd98a4/3

Answer (score 1):

Replace the second AND with an OR.

Your query is looking for records where both of the following are true:

category <> 'Fruit' and subcategory = 'Orange'

category <> 'Fruit' and subcategory = 'Apple'

Since subcategory cannot be both 'Orange' and 'Apple', one or the other is false, so the outermost AND is false.

You want to find records where either of those cases is true, so the WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE
(category <> 'Fruit' AND subcategory = 'Orange') OR
(category <> 'Fruit' AND subcategory = 'Apple')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% on what you are asking - but I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE NOT (category='Fruit' AND subcategory='Orange') AND NOT (category='Fruit' AND subcategory='Apple');
```